# Using jenkins aggregate downstream

Tags: jenkins, report, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins parent job, execute a child job using the "trigger a parameterized plugin" job. I want to transfer the results from the child job to the parent job using the aggregate downstream plugin (I don't want to use workaround like copy artifact).
[image]
There is almost no documentation on the subject.

Comment: What kind of results do you want to aggregate? Some JUnit tests?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to collect the results from some of the sub job